# Why are two files different sizes when saved and loaded back again?

Tags: python, dos

I'm using Pygame in combination with StringIO to create two files from the same source. They seem to be different sizes; why?

```
import pygame
import StringIO

putimage = pygame.image.load("88keykbd.png")
buff = StringIO.StringIO()
buff.name = '88keykbd.png'

pygame.image.save(putimage, buff)

putimage = buff.getvalue()
print "buff:", type(buff), "myimage:", type(putimage), "getimage:", type(putimage)

print len(putimage) # 110564
with open('myscrambledimage.dat', 'w') as newfile:
    newfile.write(putimage)

with open('myscrambledimage.dat', 'r') as newfile:
    getimage= newfile.read()
print len(getimage) # 7502
```

Comment: This is an interesting problem. Could you provide a *self-contained* example that we could use to reproduce it?

Comment: Hi! I don't understand what you mean by self contained. You can use any image you want if that's what you mean. But you need to have Pygame to load the image.

Comment: Try opening the files as binary.  'wb' or 'rb'.  Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using binary access for your files:

```
with open('myscrambledimage.dat', 'wb') as newfile:
    newfile.write(putimage)

with open('myscrambledimage.dat', 'rb') as newfile:
    getimage= newfile.read()
```

When you do, the sizes are consistent.  Aside from line-endings, Windows (for example) sees a CTRL+Z character as EOF.

Comment: perfect! Thank you very much cdarke for you invaluable help and response. How can I convert the "getimage" data to an image file or do I have to ask that as a separate question? Beg pardon for my ignorance.

Comment: Does not that work as it is?  I'm not all that familiar with pygame, so probably best to ask in another question.   BTW:  it would be nice if you could accept my answer.

Comment: I am truly sorry I am new to the way this works. Of course I accept your answer I now it's done!